# Doxygen - Python Module Definition with @package skips some documentation

Tags: python, doxygen

I'm documenting Python modules using Doxygen and the @package command to group each set of functions together and keep the directory structure documented.  Unfortunately, there are times when @package doesn't doesn't always do this correctly.

For example, I have 2 different sets of modules in 2 different directories:

1. `main/foo/ModuleA.py`
2. `main/bar/src/ModuleB.py`

For some reason when I markup ModuleA.py as "@package foo.ModuleA", ModuleA's documentation is 100% intact.

But when I markup ModuleB.py as `@package bar.src.ModuleB`, the documentation only contains the basic description of ModuleB, and skips all other function documentation within the file.  If I remove the "full package name" and just use `@package ModuleB`, all the documentation is included.  But if I add any additional namespace, I get only the basic description.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening?  I'm not clear on how Doxygen decides which documentation to group in with the @package and which to skip.